# abstract class A inherited by class C "through" an "intermediary" class B. How to declare the virtual fuctions?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have

```
struct Transformable {
    virtual void mirror()=0;
}

class Shape: public Transformable {
    Position position;
    Color color;
public:
    virtual void draw()=0; // 0. <-this, or
    virtual void draw(); // I. <-this, or
    void draw(); // II. <-this, or maybe
    // III. <-this?
}

class Circle {
    double radius;
public:
    void mirror();
}
```

(Where Transformable is the abstract class A, Shape is the "intermediary" class B, and Circle is C.)

Which should I use from the cases I-III (noted in //comments above)?
It doesn't make sense for Shape to have a function mirror(), so I would not want to write any code there, choosing option 0 over III.
If I would want to write code, I'd choose I over II.

If I'm right, why? If not, why?

Edit: I need class Shape for a heterogeneous collection, and I made a class Transformable to have transform functions separate from everything. Also I chose to have it go through Shape because this way I don't have to type

```
AnyShape: public Transformable, public Shape
```

only

```
AnyShape: public Shape
```

Comment: The way I see it, `Transformable` is useless. Drop it and go with `virtual void draw()=0;` inside `Shape`.

Comment: Is `Shape` going to be responsible for "drawing" anything? Then option II, else option III (if `Circle` is inheriting from `Shape` that is).

Comment: A third option, a free function that takes const Shape&?

Comment: You missed `void draw() override`

Comment: There is no need to use `virtual` in the subclass. Apart from that `void draw()=0` doesn't make sense, since omiting it will have the same result.

Comment: should Circle inherit from Shape?  (seems to conflict with title where C inherits from B)  maybe a typo.

Comment: Are `draw` and `mirror` different functions now, or were some missed when you changed the names? If they're all supposed to be the same, why does it matter for our purposes what it's called? If they're different, what effect do you think one might have on the other that both are relevant?

Comment: thanks guys! is "override" for the eyes only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the `virtual` keyword is only used in the base class. You can omit it in all derived classes and the method will nevertheless be virtual. You can still use it, but it doesn't add much except maybe for readability. Usually, in the derived classes, the keyword `override` is preferred for overridden virtual methods, because it will check at compile time that you actually override something. So you (usually) have:

```
class Base{
    virtual void method();
};

class Derived : public Base {
    void method() override; // still virtual
};
```

As for the `= 0`, you add it everywhere that there is no implementation, or where you want to force for a derived non abstract class (i.e. a class you want to instantiate in your code) to implement/override a certain method.

Note that `override` is only available if you use C++11 and above.

Answer (score 0):

```
virtual void draw() = 0; 
virtual void draw();
```

are both valid ways declaring the function in `Shape`.

The choice of whether to use the first one or the second one can be made based on what you expect `Shape` to do and what you expect its sub-types to do (`Circle` is the only one you have shown but there will be more I reckon).

If you expect that `Shape` can take care of some aspects of `draw()` but the derived classes *must* have their own implementation, then use the first option. Implement `Shape::draw()`. Derived classes can make use of `Shape::draw()` in their implementation.

If you expect that `Shape` can take care of all aspects of `draw()` for some classes, then use the second option. In this case, only those derived classes that need to override the function will override it and those that don't need to can leave it out of their implementation.

My suggestion will be to go with the first option. If there are some derived classes that don't need to do anything, they can call `Shape::draw()` and do nothing more. E.g.

```
class StrangeShape : public Shape
{
   public:
     void draw() override { Shape::draw(); }
};
```

Comment: @kabir, I'll get back to update the answer some time later this evening.